# Import all database to ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

Does anybody know is there a way to import locally all tables to clickHouse from csv or sql file (mysql dump) but not one by one table?

I found information only about table by table import https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/data-formats/csv-tsv

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/formats/#mysqldump

Comment: As I understand this is also table by table import ("It reads all data from INSERT queries belonging to one table")